# Pagination on a website where the URL stays the same python, scrapy, selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping a website that contains companies, each page contains 26 companies, I am able to login and successfully scrape the first page of the website, but have trouble figuring out how to click to the next pages and scrape those as well.

The XPath of the 'next page button' is the following: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[14]/a
I tried using a better XPath many times but this is the only one that worked. (I managed to make pagination work but then scraping was not working with another code)

Unfortunately, I am not able to provide credentials to the website.

I am using scrapy and selenium in python.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from typing_extensions import Self
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from time import sleep
from turtle import delay
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which 

#login info
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"

class HtSpiderSelenium(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ht_selenium1'
    allowed_domains = ['https://app.xxx.bootstart.tech']
    start_urls = ['https://app.xxx.bootstart.tech']
    
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://auth.bootstart.tech/auth/realms/xxxPlatform/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=xxx-platform&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.xxx.bootstart.tech%2F%3Fredirect_fragment%3D%xxx&state=8780862b-1eaf-4b6e-92e5-fd9ab464c57f&nonce=79d66ef5-f0bb-4e75-8db2-6402114b9aa8&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code")

        driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
        sleep(10)


        self.html = driver.page_source
        driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        for startup in resp.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-sm-12')]"):
            yield {
                'startup name': startup.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'no-outline ng-binding')]/text()").get(),
                'startup descript': ''.join(startup.xpath('//div//p//div//text()').getall()),
                'startup location': startup.xpath(".//h4//small[@class='ng-binding']//text()").get(),
                'startup industry': startup.xpath(".//h4//span[@class='ng-binding']/text()").get(),
            }
```

Comment: You login, then get the source, then parse the page. So now you're not logged in so you can't go to the next page. Either you handle the pagination in `__init__` and add the sources to a list, or make a selenium middleware and do the pagination with scrapy.

Comment: after clicking pagination you'll want to use a webdriver wait to find the elements.  You'll want to be able to deal with Stale Element exceptions.... so functionize the call and if you catch Stale Element exception, re-get the webelement array by re-calling the function...  to click pagination it will be helpful if there's a "next" button... your logic will follow if that button is active.

Comment: @SuperUser  once logged in it is a database, where changing between the pages does not change the URL, would it still not be possible to go to the next page? If still not possible could you help with how you would approach the two solutions you proposed?

Comment: @pcalkins could you please elaborate on how you would approach this with code? I am quite new to programming and what you are suggesting sounds feasible from other similar questions I have read, but I have trouble with how I would implement it.

Comment: Basically you want to get/re-get webelement array after clicking... (I think in Python that's driver.get_elements...) don't use page_source... that will not change as javascript is updating the DOM.  As an easy alternative to catching stale element exceptions you can just use a standard sleep to wait after you click the pagination button.  (Wait for JS to update the DOM...)  Then iterate through the webelement array to get the data you need.  (sry, I don't know Python, so can't provided specific code... you should include the relevant HTML markup so someone else can answer...)

Comment: It needs extra details